# Use php to remove &nbsp; in meta description (Magento)

Tags: php, magento

Right now I've modified this code

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

to be this code

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

and all the horrible html has been stripped from my meta descriptions that are auto generated from the description if left empty. Any idea how I could modify this to remove `&nbsp;` and replace it with a space as well?

Comment: have you tried using string replace to find `&nbsp;` and replace with ` `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289772/php-convert-html-nbsp-to-space-gt-to-etc

Comment: [`str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $this->getDescription());`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: @secretformula Not yet. I'm not sure how to do that exactly without looking it up (I'm just starting to learn PHP) and I'm not sure how to incorporate it safely into that without breaking it to be honest.

Comment: @Sam How would I do that combined with strip_tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $this->getDescription())`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will return another string with `&nbsp;` replaced with a space. This means you can just replace `$this->getDescription()` (which returns a string) with the `str_replace()` function:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $this->getDescription())) ?>" />
```

It could be a little cleaner if you break it up:

```
<?php
$description = $this->getDescription();
$description = strip_tags($description);
$description = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $description);
?>

<meta name="description" content="<?=$description?>" />
```

Note `<?=$description?>` is [shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567292/overview-of-php-shorthand) for `<?php echo $description; ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct approach is to fix the source data. You can do that in the Magento backend or update data directly in the database (db table catalog_product_entity_text, you need to find out correct attribute_id from eav_attribute db table).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [How to remove html special chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657643/how-to-remove-html-special-chars)

```
$description = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","", $description);
```

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer what is your point? Is my answer a link only?