# where should i put the mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php

i have code like this but when i click submit its give me error
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
given where should i do or put the mysqli_real_escape_string ?

```
if(!empty($_POST['poscon'])) {
        foreach($_POST['poscon'] as $condition) 
            $condition=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['poscon']);
```

Comment: read this documentation of mysqli_real_escape_string: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: yeah i know but he asked where to put it :)

Comment: you probably can't do this `foreach($_POST['poscon'] as $condition)` - if so, then you're using the wrong variable. do `$condition=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$condtion);` - see your `as $condition` ?

Comment: that should be mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$condition); because $_POST['poscon'] is an array.

Comment: can you please show us the data of $_POST['poscon']. in your question

Comment: I'm hesitant to post that as answer, as it may lead to a long haul. Too many unknowns. But if it has, let me know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- better you than some bottom feeder

Comment: I also see this as being related to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31925707/

Comment: yeah, I know @Dagon one should pop up soon

Comment: @Dagon I just don't want to be taken for a long haul neither. If the OP says "go", I'll go.

Comment: 15 mins into my code suggestion and nothing from the OP. That moment of silence says "Don't do it Fred". Yo, if you're going to want some help, you need to talk to us here.

Comment: made a typo in condition `$condition=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$condition);` - talk to me here.

Comment: OP should respond promptly to a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing you're not responding to comments, I'm posting this as an answer.
*- Maybe you'll respond then.*

You see your `foreach($_POST['poscon'] as $condition)`?

You're using the wrong parameter and passing the array instead of the `$condition` variable.

Do `$condition=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$condition);`

Comment: Please give me example before `mysqli_real_escape_string` and after the string which gets generated. As it casuse confusion and no example is given.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Given that the OP did not supply anything else in their question, I won't be able to provide you with that information, other than visiting the PHP.net's website on the function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and tutorials site.

Comment: Hi Fred, there is NO input and output after using the function. And I checked Lots of answers here but nothing gave me output after applying function. Maybe you can supply us answer!

Comment: @PratikCJoshi you need to post a question about this. Stack doesn't approve about responding to questions for someone else. Sorry, but that's how Stack works.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you taking  user inputs from the view you should check.

**`mysqli_real_escape_strin`g Definition**

This function is used to create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement. The given string is encoded to an escaped SQL string, taking into account the current character set of the connection.

[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) Manual

1. Normal text

   ```
   Early `$name = $_POST['name'];`        
   New Practice `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])`
   ```
2. URL

   ```
   Early `$url = $_POST['url'];`        
   New Practice `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` [Check Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp)
   ```
3. E-Mail

   ```
   Early `$email = $_POST['email'];`        
   New Practice `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` [Check Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp)
   ```

More Useful Articles

1. [Is mysqli_real_escape_string safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304930/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-safe)
2. [mysql(i)_real_escape_string, safe to rely on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390125/mysqli-real-escape-string-safe-to-rely-on)
3. [mysqli::real_escape_string, mysqli_real_escape_string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.real-escape-string.html)