# has() always true when using null coalesce operator?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following code in my form currently:

```
{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}
```

I tried changing it to this:

```
{{ $errors->has('email') ?: ' has-error' }}
```

But now the class is added even if it has no errors. Why is this happening? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems null coalescing works bit differently then ternary even if the variable is `empty ( '' )` i.e false the null coalescing will treat the variable as `true` but the shorthand ternary operator won't. And that's something to have in mind.

https://3v4l.org/fnG9W

for more info on null coalescing vs ternary.

[PHP ternary operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 1):

That's how null coalesce operator works. For example, this will return 5:

```
false ?: 5
```

When you use `has()` method which will return `true` or `false`, null coalesce operator will always return `'has-error'`.

So, just use the ternary operator.