# PHP Ternary operator

Tags: php, string

Hi everyone below is my PHP code. I have basically made an algorithm so when a name is inputted in the $string section, that name is searched and depending on the first letter in the name it will be placed within a group, either group 1 or 2.

I run into a problem as whenever i search for a name beginning with P it outputs group 2 when it should be group 1. any idea why this is? i need it to output group 1 with names a-p and group 2 for names after p.

```
$string = "Peter"; //Input surname here!

$firstCharacter = substr($string, 0, 1); //Finds the first letter in the String
$firstCharacter = strtoupper($string); //Converts string into uppercase

echo ($string > 'P') ? 'Group1' : 'Group2';
```

Comment: Try `>=` for greater-than-or-equal. I'd make this an answer, but really, this is basic comparison.

Comment: This might be useful too...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: also more of a code-style thing but helps code-readability, if you keep the inline if statement all inside brackets, it's easier to see where it begins and where it ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'P' is not greater than 'P', it is equal to 'P', thus your condition is marked false for 'P'. You can either change your condition to >=, or condition on the letter after 'P', 'Q'.

Comment: when i change it to >= it says group 2 for letters a-p when i need it to be group 1. do i just switch these around?

Comment: Yeah, either swap your groups in the ternary outcomes or change the >= to a <=