# Using null coalescing operator to echo an escaped output

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

is there a possiblity to use the null coalescing operator AND echo in one expression like this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) ?? '';
```

As a short form of

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  echo htmlspechars($_POST['email']);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To help you understand the null coalescing operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP ternary operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null coalescing operator won't emit a `E_NOTICE` when a parameter isn't defined.

So you could do `$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'] ?? '');`

Note that the null coalescing operator is applied to the **variable** (`$_POST['email']`) and **not** to the result of `htmlspecialchars()`.

If you wanted to use conditional ternary operator (`?:`), then you should have to check if the variable is set before operating on it.

```
if ( isset($_POST['email']) ) {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'] ?: '');
}
```

Note that `isset()` will be `TRUE` if the variable **is set** (or, in other words, it is **defined** and has a value different than `NULL`).

Comment: isset() can't be null and return true. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: But i get this error: "Undefined index: email". Any ideas why?

Comment: @michiman are you using `??` **inside** the parenthesis of `htmlspecialchars()`? Note that I do it inside of them.

Comment: @AlejandroIván thats so nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlejandroIván isset() and defined are two different things. isset() will return false even you assign null to a variable. You're mixing that up with empty(). empty() equals your definition of defined. See this example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c413ea1da71a3815b97069b75198331c884a4d5b