# Loop multidimensional array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

Im having trouble looping an array in my laravel 5.5 blade

1.- In my controller Im querying a dynamodb and I'm returning $arrayRet

```
 $result =$dynamodb->query(array(
            'TableName' => 'sigfox',
            'KeyConditionExpression' => 'deviceid = :v_hash',
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
                ':v_hash'  => array('S' => '3E6231')
            )
        ));

        //echo "Query succeeded.\n";
        $arrayRet['signals'] = $result['Items'];
  return view('loggers.index', $arrayRet);
```

2.-In my blade I have the following code

```
 @foreach($signals as $signal)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$signal['payload']['M']['data']['S']}}</td>  
        </tr>
 @endforeach
```

3.- I get Undefined index: data --- So I've dd($signal) and this is the result

```
array:3 [▼
"payload" => array:1 [▼
      "M" => array:10 [▼
  "avgSnr" => array:1 [▶]
  "rssi" => array:1 [▶]
  "data" => array:1 [▼
    "S" => "33333b414900"
  ]
  "lng" => array:1 [▶]
  "snr" => array:1 [▶]
  "station" => array:1 [▶]
  "seqNumber" => array:1 [▶]
  "time" => array:1 [▶]
  "device" => array:1 [▶]
  "lat" => array:1 [▶]
   ]
   ]
"deviceid" => array:1 [▶]
"timestamp" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

4.- I also tried getting the value hardcoding the position and It works. But I have to use the "blade way" with @foreach

```
       <tr>
            <td>{{$signals[0]['deviceid']['S']}}</td>
            <td>{{$signals[0]['timestamp']['S']}}</td>
            <td>{{$signals[0]['payload']['M']['avgSnr']['S']}}</td>
            <td>{{$signals[0]['payload']['M']['snr']['S']}}</td>
            <td>{{$signals[0]['payload']['M']['lat']['S']}}</td>
            <td>{{$signals[0]['payload']['M']['lng']['S']}}</td>
        </tr>
```

5.- Maybe I'm missing something please advise

Comment: You've 3 items in the array, could it be possible that the first item has all the index but not the 2nd or 3rd item?

Comment: Im not sure how the table was created but yes it is possible. Actually if i do {{$signal['payload']['M']}} in my blade. It tells me that a string is expected but an array is given instead, which make sense.

Comment: As it shows, it's possible that some rows might have inconsistent structure in them. What you have to concern is how will you handle when the target structure is missing. Please tell me your purpose of what you are doing and the output you want, so I can suggest you the appropriate solution on it.

Comment: Also in your hardcoding you didn't change the `$signals` index. As a result, it may not move to the next row and then error.

Comment: @spicydog I need to present deviceid, timestamp and all the payload elements in a table. If any of the above is missing I just skip it. The information comes from a IoT enabled device which reports every 10 minutes. So it is not a big deal if I miss one.

Comment: @N3b0 are you using PHP7 ?

Comment: Yes. PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 7 [null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator) can be very useful here!

```
@foreach(signals as signal)
   <tr>
        <td>{{ $signal['deviceid']['S'] ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['timestamp']['S'] ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['payload']['M']['avgSnr']['S'] ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['payload']['M']['snr']['S'] ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['payload']['M']['lat']['S'] ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['payload']['M']['lng']['S'] ?? 'N/A' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

If the index doesn't exist, it will print "N/A" as a default value.

There can be more improvement! Create a model to clean up these indexes and everything before sending the view and the code will look something like this. In your controller, process this data before sending it to view. The function like `array_map` can be useful here. Logic staff should be done out of the views as much as possible. Your code will look much neater.

```
@foreach(signals as signal)
   <tr>
        <td>{{ $signal['deviceid'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['timestamp'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['avgSnr'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['snr'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['lat'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $signal['lng'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. I will work on the model. I will try a diferent array not the default DynamoDB Json format.