# What does this php operator do?

Tags: php

```
$serial = ($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL'] ?? false);
```

It looks like a bit like a ternary. But for that I would have expected:

```
$serial = $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL'] ?  $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL'] : false
```

perhaps it's shorthand, but finding a link to confirm is difficult. I found the snippet in php4 legacy code.

(note this is php not c#)

Comment: _“but finding a link to confirm is difficult”_ - typing “php double question mark” into Google would have lead you to the duplicate in no time …

Comment: thanks, knowing what to search for is half the battle. I was trying '??' instead of 'double question mark

Answer (score 1):

> I found the snippet in php4 legacy code

That's weird. As far as I know, [it was added in PHP 7](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

From the docs:

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

Comment: you are correct, it is legacy code, but this line is newer. thanks.

Answer (score -5):

its what to do if

```
    if null
```

[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) ps: you're welcome thanks for the minus 2, loads of languages use this, most notably swift

Comment: seriously why the double minus for answering the question within 12 seconds correctly?

Comment: 1) If it's a duplicate, vote to close as duplicate. 2) "its what to do if if null" is a terrible answer.

Comment: `What does this php operator do? ` ... `it's what to do if if null`