# How can this code to be more shorter?

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I'm newbie to PHP and I have a simple question.

**UPDATE**: I am using PHP 5.6 (Best solution would be to update the PHP version but let's suppose that I can only use PHP 5.6)

I have a code like below:

```
function findOrCreateMasterRecord ($masterTableName, $masterName) {

    if (isset($sampleArr[$masterTableName][$masterName])) {
        return $sampleArr[$masterTableName][$masterName];
    }

    return getNewMasterIndex($masterTableName, $masterName);

}
```

This code works properly. But I want to make "if" block more simple because **it approaches twice to same index**($sampleArr[$masterTableName][$masterName]) and I think this is...somewhat..not good.

Is there a way to make this function to be more effective?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using PHP 7+ then you can make use of the [null coalescing operator (`??`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: I would leave it as is, and concentrate on stuff that has more impact, to be honest. Sure, in php7 you could make it it somewhat more readable using `??`, but that doesn't really do anything much different. It does need you (see answer below) maybe to shorten your variables to something unreadable to keep it in one line. That's a bigger no-no then your current check in my book

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is working and should therefore be posted on code review.

Comment: I would totally vote in favor of what @Nanne has mentioned. In terms of learning the language, this is an interesting question to ask. I wouldn't think there are any real world benefits to shortening the code for the sake for shortening it (reducing method complexity is good but it doesn't always correlate with line numbers)

Comment: There is a bug in this code, making condition pointless. The variable $sampleArr is never set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **PHP 7+** you could use the [**null coalescing operator:** `??`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

```php
function findOrCreateMasterRecord ($masterTableName, $masterName)
{
    return $sampleArr[$masterTableName][$masterName] ?? getNewMasterIndex($masterTableName, $masterName);
}
```

If not in PHP 7, a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP) could shorten your code but will still be redundant:

```php
function findOrCreateMasterRecord ($masterTableName, $masterName)
{
    return isset($sampleArr[$masterTableName][$masterName]) ? $sampleArr[$masterTableName][$masterName] : getNewMasterIndex($masterTableName, $masterName);
}
```

---

With shorter variable names for a better read:

```php
// PHP 7
function findOrCreateMasterRecord ($table, $name)
{
    return $arr[$table][$name] ?? getNewMasterIndex($table, $name);
}

// Under PHP 7
function findOrCreateMasterRecord ($table, $name)
{
    return isset($arr[$table][$name]) ? $arr[$table][$name] : getNewMasterIndex($table, $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce to the following, as your condition will never be met:

```
<?php
function findOrCreateMasterRecord ($masterTableName, $masterName) {
    return getNewMasterIndex($masterTableName, $masterName);
}
```