# while calculation in array_sum` if null value in array, then use $stoploss as `$exit_price

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to make statement : **while calculation in** `array_sum` if `$stoploss` is null in array, then use $stoploss as `$exit_price`

in below statement:

```
$expectancy_a = array_sum(($exit_price - ($stoploss)))/$number_trades;
```

`$stoploss` has below value:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => 425
  3 => null
  4 => 77
]
```

how can i say in that statement, if $stoploss has null value then, take $exit_price as $stoploss.

I tired with `if` condition:

```
if (in_array(null, $stoploss, true)) {
$r_multiple[] = ($exit_price - $entry_price) / ($entry_price - $stoploss);
}
```

Comment: >  if $stoploss is null in array,

Frankly, I don't understand what do you mean by that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator should help.

Comment: Can you provide all vars values and expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider mapping $stoploss with a closure that uses null-coalescing:

```
$corrected = array_map(function($value) use ($exit_price) {
    return $value ?? $exit_price;
}, $stoploss);
```

This will convert all null values to $exit_price from the $stoploss array.

Comment: Beat me too it, consider a link to the documentation too though? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati, your suggested edit seems off, $corrected is still an array.  You still need to use array_sum or you could do null-coalescing in an array_reduce function instead of mapping then summing.