# array_key_exists and ?? in php 7.x

Tags: php, syntax

This code works in PHP 7.x

```
$array = ['asda' => ['asdasd']];
$var = $array['asda']['asdasd'] ?? "yes!";
echo $var;
```

If we replace `??` with `?:` as we have in older PHP version, this code will not work, for example:

```
$array = ['asda' => ['asdasd']];
$var = $array['asda']['asdasd'] ? $array['asda']['asdasd'] : "yes!";
echo $var;
```

It means, we will get an error like:
`Notice</b>:  Undefined index: asdasd in <b>[...][...]</b> on line`

So, can we use the first example in PHP 7.x without afraid about anything strange/unexpected `in behind`? I mean, is it safe to use this instead, for example, `array_key_exists` or `isset`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

please refer this like, this is an new feature in 7.x  *Null coalescing operator* yes it safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isset()` to test if the element exists.

```
$var = isset($array['asda']['asdasd']) ? $array['asda']['asdasd'] : "yes!";
```

The old `:?` conditional operator is a simple `if/then/else` -- it tests the truthiness of the first expression, and then returns either the second or third expression depending on this. The test expression is executed normally, so if it involves undefined variables, indexes, or properties you'll get a normal warning about it.

The new `??` null-coalescing operator, on the other hand, tests whether the first expression is defined and not `NULL`, not just whether it's truthy. Since it does it's own check for whether the expression is defined, it doesn't produce a warning when it's not. It's specifically intended as a replacement for the `isset()` conditional.

See [PHP ternary operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: You might want to point out what the difference between the two operators `?:` and `??` is, so the op understands better as to why his code isn't working as intended.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some explanation, along with a link to a related question.