# Why PHP isset and Null coalescing operator is throwing Notice with concatenation operator?

Tags: php, php-7

I have read that PHP isset and null coalescing operator used to ignore **PHP Notice:  Undefined index:**

I have seen this post also
[PHP ternary operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

But I am getting PHP notice with both of them while using them with string concatenation operator:

```
<?php
    $array = ['a'=>'d'];

    $c = $array['c'] ?? '';
    $d = isset($array['c']) ? $array['c'] : '';
    $val = "sgadjgjsd".$array['c'] ?? ''; // PHP Notice:  Undefined index: c in /home/cg/root/986045/main.php on line 6
    $val2 = "sgadjgjsd".isset($array['c']) ? $array['c'] : ''; // PHP Notice:  Undefined index: c in /home/cg/root/986045/main.php on line 7
?>
```

**EDIT:**

I know This can be solved by the following methods

1) assigning to variable like

```
$val = "sgadjgjsd".$c = $array['c'] ?? '';
```

2) using @

```
$val = "sgadjgjsd".@$array['c'] ?? '';
```

3) adding brackets (and as Karsten suggested )

```
$val = "sgadjgjsd".($array['c'] ?? '');
```

But I am looking for the reason behind it.

Comment: use brackets around `("sgadjgjsd".$array['c'])`. Operator `.` [has higher precedence than the terniary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: Thank you @KarstenKoop for your reply, but I am looking for the reason behind it.

Comment: because you concatenate before the ternary comes into effect, so the notice is from the concatenation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every operator has its own 'importance' ([operator precedence](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), as @Karsten-koop pointed out) which dictates in what order they are executed. For example:

```
echo 10 + 5 * 3; // 25 (10+15), not 45 (15×3)
```

In this case:

```
$val = "sgadjgjsd".$array['c'] ?? '';
```

PHP will do the following steps:

1. Concatenate (.) the string `sgadjgjsd` with the value of `$array['c']`.
2. `$array['c']` does not exist, so a notice is emitted.
3. The end result (`sgadjgjsd`) is then run through the  null coalescing operator, and since the string is not equal to null, the string is returned (not `''`).
4. The end result is assigned to a variable named `$val`.

So why does 10 + 5 * 3 equal 25? Look up the `*` and `+` operators in the table on the linked page. Notice that `*` is higher up in the list, so it goes first.
For the other example, the concatenation opereator `.` is (quite a bit) higher up than `??`.

Using brackets is the proper solution; they allow you to specify what goes first:

```
echo (10 + 5) * 3;
$val = "sgadjgjsd".($array['c'] ?? '');
// Does ?? first and returns either the value of $array['c'] or ''
// and only then it does the string concatenation and assignment to $val.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

*Side-note: You might recognise this same concept from school because the same thing exists in mathematics* ([some historical background on *why*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/827988)).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you want to concatenate a string with a null in first case and in second case with boolean value

```
$val = $array['c'] ?? '';
```

will not gonna throw any error but concatenating total different data type with different one will throw error.