# The new PHP7 "null coalescing" operator gives an Undefined index notice?

Tags: php

In PHP7+ there is this new "Null coalescing operator." - http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op  It says:

```
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';
```

In that case, why does this code result in error/notice:

```
$username = (int)($_GET['user']) ?? 'nobody';
```

> Notice:  Undefined index: user

Is it the expected behavior (if so, doesn't it defy the purpose of this operator)? Similar notice when changing `(int)` to `(string)` etc.

Comment: Because the cast to int takes precedence over the null coalescing operator

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Hopefully it will be changed in the future versions - it makes this operator useless in many cases :

Comment: Just use parentheses

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571460/1691103  might provide some insight