# Can't see the error with my code for "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php

I'd be grateful if anyone can cast an eye over this error with my php? It worked locally but when I published it live it generated this error:

******* UPDATE: If there is null data then the error is created so I need to create an ELSE statement right?

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [line #]
```

Thanks for all input and help!

```
                <?php
                $categories = get_the_category();
                foreach($categories as $cat):?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id);?>" class="badge badge-primary" style="margin-bottom:5px;"><?php echo $cat->name;?></a>

                <br>

                <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php
                $tags = get_the_tags();
                foreach($tags as $tag):?>

                  <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id);?>" class="badge badge-light"><?php echo $tag->name;?></a>

                <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($categories);` and `var_dump($tags);`. The error pops up when the argument is invalid (not an array or object). Most likely either one of them (or both) is returning null.

Comment: Yes indeed - I discovered that if it is NULL then the error comes about...so need an "ELSE" statement...

Comment: Just wrap it inside `if (is_array($categories) || is_object($categories)) { ... } else { // do something else here }`

Comment: PHP 7? If is `if(is_iterable($categories)) { foreach ....` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php

Comment: Is this wordpress related? Seems like some sort of framework. Relevant maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Either `$categories` or `$tags` is not an array, likely a `null`. If you expect this, you can - in modern versions of PHP - sidestep the issue:

```
foreach(($categories ?? []) as $cat):
```

or

```
foreach(($tags ?? []) as $tag):
```

Where:

- [`??`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34571330/2908724) is the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand side if it's non-empty, otherwise the right-hand side.
- `[]` is short array syntax, and equivalent to `array ()`

So this says to use, for example, `$tags` if it's not-empty otherwise use an empty array. This handles most use cases, provided your getter methods return either an array or a null.

Note that the surrounding parentheses are optional; I prefer their readability. You could just as well do, for example, `foreach($tags ?? [] as $tag):`

Comment: It should be noted that the ?? null-coalescing operator is PHP 7+ exclusive.