# PHP Null coalescing operator usage

Tags: php, laravel, null-coalescing-operator

Having this example code using the tertiary operator in PHP, I get the 'default value'.

```
$myObject = null; // I'm doing this for the example
$result = $myObject ? $myObject->path() : 'default value';
```

However, when I try to use the null coalescing operator to do this, I get the error

**Call to a member function path() on null**

```
$result = $myObject->path() ?? 'default value';
```

What am I doing wrong with the ?? operator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These snippets do not work in the same way:

`$result = $myObject ? $myObject->path() : 'default value';` says: use `'default value'` if `$myObject` is `NULL`

`$result = $myObject->path() ?? 'default value';` says: use the default if `$myObject->path()` returns `NULL` - but that call can only return something if the object itself is not `NULL`

Comment: Oh ok cool. So I should be able to chain ?? operator. But then if I do that, what's the point, I might as well use the tertiary operator...

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve :) As far as I see, the first code you are using does what it should, and there is no shorter way

Comment: Yup, thought so... i edited my comment. As you say, there is no shorter way, so what would be the point

Answer (score 4):

`??` will work if the left hand side is null or not set, however in your case the left hand cannot be evaluated if `$myObject` is null.

What you should consider in your case is the new [nullsafe operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator) available with PHP 8 (so need to wait on that)

```
$result = $myObject?->path() ?? 'default value';
```

This should make the left hand side null if `$myObject` is null

Until then you can just do:

```
$result = ($myObject ? $myObject->path() : null) ?? 'default value';
```

This differs from your first use case in that you get `default value` if either `$myObject` **or** `$myObject->path()` are null

Comment: Oh cool. Yes that's the operator I'm looking for! Which is what i would use in Swift. Thanks