# Extra whitespaces in blade statements. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

The problem is, it's not just one variable, but statements with `@if`, `@isset` and `@foreach` directives. I can't remove whitespaces without syntax error. And all these whitespaces are displaying in input fields.

In description field I did this:

1. Check, if `old('description')` exists.
2. If yes, display it.
3. If not, then check, if variable `$post` exists (I use this form for store and update methods both).
4. If yes, display it.
5. If not, the field remains empty.

   ```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3">@if(old('description')){{ old('description') }}@else @isset ($post){{$post->description}}@endisset @endif</textarea>
   ```

   ```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
    <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags"
           value="@isset ($post, $tags)@foreach($post->tagged as $tagged){{$tagged->tag_name}},@endforeach @endisset">
   ```

I tried package *hedronium/spaceless-blade*, but it doesn't work with input values.

Comment: ErrorException 
Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Comment: Try again `isset(old('description')) ? old('description') : isset($post) ?  $post->description : NULL;`

Comment: "isset only works with variables and arrays". I changed `isset(old('description'))` to `old('description')` and get the same error as above.

Comment: `old('description', $post->description ?? null) ` or `old('description', optional($post)->description)` should work

Comment: @lagbox first works for both methods, second - only for `update`, not `store`. Thanks!

Comment: @lagbox by the way, how to do the same with checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>@if` and `"@isset` will be parsed as string because `@` will be parsed as syntax only if not join together with other character except space, new line or tab. You can do if condition without @ inside `{{}}`.

I have a better solution using [ternary operator and null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator).

change your long code

```
@if(old('description')){{ old('description') }}@else @isset ($post){{$post->description}}@endisset @endif
```

to

```
{{old('description') ?? isset($post)?$post->description:''}}
```

and change

```
@isset ($post, $tags)@foreach($post->tagged as $tagged){{$tagged->tag_name}},@endforeach @endisset
```

to

```
{{isset($post) ? implode(', ', $post->tagged->pluck('tag_name')->toArray() )):''}}
```

so the full code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3">{{old('description') ?? isset($post)?$post->description:''}}</textarea>
</div>


 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="tags">Tags</label>
 <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags"
           value="{{isset($post) ? implode(', ', $post->tagged->pluck('tag_name')->toArray() )):''}}">
</div>
```

Comment: I changed code, and in description field doesn't display `old('description')`. In tags field appears an error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')'

Comment: old('description') will be shown if you use redirect with `->withInput();`

Comment: for tags I updated the code, just wrong at function arg

Comment: Old description still not working with `withInput()`. In my code it worked without `withInput()`, but with extra spaces. In tag input new error - "Undefined variable: tag_name", because "tagged" from pivot table was not used, I think.

Comment: change `$tag_name` to `$post->tagged`

Comment: `old()` will never working without `withInput()`, maybe you used form validation? it's included `withInput()`. and it's strange if not working, try to change to `{{ old('description') }}` will  it show?

Comment: "array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given". "tagged" - it's array of post's tags from other table. I used this package https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging

Comment: Yes, I use validation. With only `{{ old('description') }}` it works.

Comment: so it's a collection, just change to `{{isset($post) ? implode(', ', $post->tagged->pluck('tag_name')->toArray() )):''}}`

Comment: and try to change `??` to `?:`

Comment: I changed `??` to `?:`, and appeared an error: Unparenthesized `a ?: b ? c : d` is deprecated. Use either `(a ?: b) ? c : d` or `a ?: (b ? c : d)`. Then I added brackets: `{{ (old('description') ?: isset($post))?$post->description:'' }}`. $post value shows, but `old()` - doesn't.

Comment: it's very strange if doesn't work. But sorry I can't replicate your issue without full code.
what about tagged, is it worked?

Comment: About tags. I removed one extra bracket and whitespace after comma, and it's work now - `{{isset($post) ? implode(',', $post->tagged->pluck('tag_name')->toArray() ):''}}`. So, half of the problem is solved, thank you. Now tags field doesn't contain extra spaces.

Comment: And about description. When I use `{{old('description') ?? isset($post)?$post->description:''}}` in create form, where there is no variable $post, and when I make a deliberate mistake with validation to test `old()`, I get an error: "Undefined variable: post". When I don't make validation mistakes and have no redirect back, form works well. Only {{ old('description') }} works as it should and returns old value. So, the problem with syntax somewhere here: `{{old('description') ?? isset($post)?$post->description:''}}`, I think. When I change `??` to `?:`, result the same.

Comment: I fix the problem with "description". If you're interested, you can check my own answer to this question. Your answer is accepted anyway, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, using directive `@php`.

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3">@php
        if(old('description')) {
            echo old('description');
        } elseif (isset($post)){
            echo $post->description;
        } 
    @endphp</textarea>
```

No more extra whitespaces.