# PHP - what is the point of using isSet() and checking for truthy value?

Tags: php, if-statement, isset, truthy

I saw this in my codebase today:

```
if (isset($purchase_data['buyer_tracking_address_id']) && $purchase_data['buyer_tracking_address_id']) {
    // do something
}
```

Why would checking for both conditions be necessary? Isn't using just the first clause enough?

Comment: No. A variable can be set and have a false value (false, empty string, 0). !empty can condense this into 1 check

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't using just the first clause enough?

**Edit** I see the context of your question changed while I typed this answer. I think aynber's comment answers your question.

---

`isset` is really only there to check for the existence of the array key *buyer_tracking_address_id* before the the next operation tries to access it. If it doesn't exist, *isset* will return false and will prevent the next condition from running.

Without `isset`, if you tried to access the array key *buyer_tracking_address_id* and it didn't exist, PHP would throw a warning.

> Warning:  Undefined array key "buyer_tracking_address_id"

The following code will throw [a notice in PHP 7](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc69701373e6e2c949985e302aa914bcf88b511d), and [a warning in PHP 8](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbbfe46c9c0b913ecf3dcb32685e5555c981f9bf).

```
<?php

$purchase_data = [
    'buyer_tracking_address_id' => '12345'    
];

if ($purchase_data['doesnt_exist']) {
    // do something
}
```

It is also worthwhile reading and understanding [the *ternary operator* and the *null coalescing operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571460/296555) as they are often used to access unknown array keys.