# PHP Print "null" instead of nothing

Tags: php, php-8

I'd like to ask if it's possible to print "null" instead of nothingness in php8. Let me explain:

```php
$player = null;
echo $player;
```

**What it prints**:
**What I want:** null

Comment: null is a empty string, its like echo '';

Comment: I have rolled back your most recent edit. Do not add the solution to the question; post it as an answer below, or accept the answer that was posted properly in the meantime.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. I was about to comment an answer but someone already answered again. I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what "nothingness" means to you, you could use one of the following:

```
echo $player ?? 'null'; // null coalescing operator

// or

echo $player ? $player : 'null'; // ternary operator

// or

echo !empty($player) ? $player : 'null'; // ternary operator with empty() check, which will not throw an error when the $player variable does not exist 

// or

echo $player ?: 'null'; // ternary operator shorthand
```

More info here: [PHP ternary operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: For `null` specific ternary options that can be added as opposed to conditionally falsey values (`0, "", false`), Use `null === $player ? 'null' : $player` and `isset($player) ? $player : 'null'`