# PHP - Undefined index solving returns warining

Tags: php, isset, undefined-index

I have a function within my PHP project which has some specific params..

```
 $user_sequence = $user['user_sequence'];

 if ($cached || !$user_sequence) {
    return;
 }
```

> Notice: Undefined index: user_sequence

I have fixed that with:

```
        if (isset($user['user_sequence'])) {                     
           $user_sequence = $user['user_sequence'];     
         }
```

But now my second `if()` clause get's a warning:

> Variable '$user_sequence' is probably undefined

Would setting it to **null** before `if()` be the best approach to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Using the null coalescing operator would be a bit more "tidy" perhaps. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 0):

Spelled out in full, you need to specify what the value should be if `$user['user_sequence']` is *not* set. In your second if statement, you are checking `!$user_sequence`, so a logical default value would be boolean `false`:

```
if (isset($user['user_sequence'])) {                     
   $user_sequence = $user['user_sequence'];
}
else {
   $user_sequence = false;
}
```

Luckily, PHP doesn't make use write out that whole `if` statement, because we can use [the null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), and shorten it to this:

```
$user_sequence = $user['user_sequence'] ?? false;
```

In other situations, you might want to default to an empty array (`$something ?? []`) or even just `null` (`$something ?? null`).