# Php ternary operator - Am I using ?: correctly?

Tags: php

I just cannot figure what is going wrong so I am asking for help.

This is my statement:

```
  $fs_ski_resorts_data[$i]['fs_ski_resort_aa_zoom'] =
         get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_fs_aa_zoom') ?:
        get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_qgis_aa_zoom');
```

There are two fields called:

(1) `fs_ski_resort_data_fs_aa_zoom`

(2) `fs_ski_resort_data_qgis_aa_zoom`

If there is a value entered int (1)  `fs_ski_resort_data_fs_aa_zoom` , I want to assign it to  `$fs_ski_resorts_data[$i]['fs_ski_resort_aa_zoom']` .  If not, use the  fallback of (2)  `fs_ski_resort_data_qgis_aa_zoom`  is to be assigned to `$fs_ski_resorts_data[$i]['fs_ski_resort_aa_zoom']`.

I thought `?:` was correct but maybe not.  What would be the correct shorthand for the above, please?

I have about 300 records.  All of them have values in `fs_ski_resort_data_fs_aa_zoom` but despite this, sometime I get NULL as the value of `$fs_ski_resorts_data[$i]['fs_ski_resort_aa_zoom']` which is sometimes the value of `fs_ski_resort_data_qgis_aa_zoom`.

Any help appreciated.

I think I have followed all the advice but I do not get the results as expected and as described about.  While I appreciated the links, I have read already a ton and just cannot see what I am doing wrong.  Anyone able to tell me specifically what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: [How to use the PHP Ternary Operator](https://www.codementor.io/@sayantinideb/ternary-operator-in-php-how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator-x0ubd3po6). You're using the ternary shorthand operator.

Comment: If you just want to use `fs_ski_resort_data_fs_aa_zoom` if it is not null (rather than true), then use the null coalescing operator `??` instead

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-short-ternary-elvis-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: `?:` aka Elvis operator.

Comment: Elvis operator `?:` will fallback to the second value whenever the first value is "falsey". In your case, if "fs_ski_resort_data_fs_aa_zoom" is `0` or less than `0`, the assignment will still fallback to the second value. If you want to fallback only when the first value is "" or `null`, then you should use the null coalescing operator `??` instead.