# why Coverity scan tells the code " $data ?? [] " is logically dead code?

Tags: php, laravel-9, php-8.1, coverity

Below are the comments given by Coverity scan. Here there is a chance that $data become undefined, but the code "$data ?? []" will solve that issue. If $data is null output of this code will be []. I dont understand what is issue here.

```
//assignment: Assigning: $data = undefined.
     public function addPromotions( Array $promotions )
     {
         foreach($promotions as $promotion)
//implied_types: $data[] implies that the type of $data must be array.
         { $data[] = ['PromoCode' => $promotion->claim_code, 'PromotionName' => $promotion->name]; }
//possible_types: At condition $data, the type of $data must be one of undefined and array.
//dead_error_condition: The condition $data must be true.
//CID 15805 (#1 of 1): Logically dead code (DEADCODE)
//dead_error_line: Execution cannot reach this statement: var <storage from new>;.**
         if( $data ?? [] )
         { $this->post('/current/api/AddPromotions', $data); }
     }
```

Below is actual code

```
     public function addPromotions( Array $promotions )
     {
         foreach($promotions as $promotion)
         { $data[] = ['PromoCode' => $promotion->claim_code, 'PromotionName' => $promotion->name]; }

         if( $data ?? [] )
         { $this->post('/current/api/AddPromotions', $data); }
     }
```

In some cases ( empty $promotions array ), we get below error
**WARNING Undefined variable $data**
To tackle this kind of error, I used "$data ?? []". Because, if $data is undefined, it evaluates to null when using this operator and returns []. There are alternative code for this. But I didn't get the issue with my usage. There are 3 cases for $data

1. $data is non-empty arrray
2. $data is empty ([])
3. $data is undefined

Here 1st two cases, 2nd operand (of $data ?? []) wont consider. But in the 3rd case, 2nd operand will be considered. In that case how this will become a dead code. IMO, a dead code is something which never executed in any case.

Comment: Why do you need to use `?? []` in any way? Which kind of problem does it solve? To me, that does not look like a proper check for "is $data defined"

Comment: Static analysis is not perfect. This looks like a false positive in Coverity.

Comment: In the code you've shared, the second case ($data is empty) can never occur

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can adjust your code to address the concerns and ensure proper handling of $data:

```
public function addPromotions(Array $promotions) {
    $data = [];
    foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
        $data[] = ['PromoCode' => $promotion->claim_code, 'PromotionName' => $promotion->name];
    }
    if ($data) {
        $this->post('/current/api/AddPromotions', $data);
    } else {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: @DarkBee, thanks for your reply. But usage of "$data ?? []" is not wrong. Correct ?

Comment: This is not my answer. Sure it's not wrong, but declaring the variable up front and then testing with `if ($data) {` is more clean imho

Comment: Any idea what is meant by "Logically dead code" ?. I believe it is not a dead code , it will be evaluated on every function call

Comment: My guess would be it's because your function doesn't return any value, which a function should do

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. The OP didn't ask how do **change** the code such that the scanner doesn't mention the given problem

Answer (score 0):

### An empty array evaluates to false

If `$data` evaluates to false the empty array created by `$data ?? []` will evaluate to false as well. Creating the empty array is therefore redundant and can be removed.

1. `if` checks for the true-ish value of a statement.
2. The expression `$data ?? []` checks if `$data` exists and if not creates an empty array to be evaluated for the if condition
3. An empty array is treated as false in a condition expression (`var_dump((bool) array()); // false`)
4. So again, when `$data` evaluates to false, the empty array is also false and won't change the outcome of the if condition.

This means that you might just as well write `if( isset($data) )`. If you initialize `$data` as an empty array you can also use `!empty($data)` to be more explicitly checking if something is in the array.

Also see:

- [SO: PHP short ternary "Elvis" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-short-ternary-elvis-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)
- [PHP docs: operator comparison - ??](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)
- [PHP docs: booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)
- [PHP docs: empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php)

Comment: If you feed the method with an empty array, code will not enter the loop where the variable is defined. If you just do `if ($data)`, you'll get a warning: https://3v4l.org/3Sa10#v8.3.2

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Okay sure I changed the answer to say `isset($data)`  makes sense.

Comment: @Peter Pointer, Thanks for your reply.
In some cases ( empty $promotions array ), we get below error
 WARNING  Undefined variable $data
To tackle this kind of error, I used "$data ?? []". Because, if $data is undefined, it evaluates to null when using this operator and returns [].
We cannot use if( $data ) or if( !$data ). It will return above error. We can use if( !empty($data)).  I know there are alternative code for this. But I didn't get issue with my usage......

Comment: @xman please add all such clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section. Why not define the variable properly if such an error pops up?

Comment: There are 3 cases for $data
1. $data is non-empty arrray
2. $data is empty ([])
3. $data is undefined 
Here 1st 2 cases , 2nd operand (of $data ?? []) wont consider. But in the 3rd case 2nd operand will be considered. Then how this will become dead code

Comment: As said, please add those clarifications to your question. If you always initialize $data as an empty array (`$data = []`) you can check with `!empty($data)` . You think you have to fix accessing the non-existent variable. Instead you could use `isset` for example. The dead code is still about creating this empty array I rescribed in my answer, which evaluates to false. The proper way to check if a variable exists is obviously not creating an empty array as a side-effect. Please try to understand.