Always keep WooCommerce "View cart" button visible for products that are in Cart
I want the "View cart" ("Voir le panier" in French) button to remain visible for products I've added to cart in WooCommerce, even after refreshing the page.
Right now, the buttons disappear when I refresh. I need help with this feature to ensure that the product remains displayed, similar to the screenshot below.

Actually, I have this in add-to-cart.php template file:
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$is_in_cart = false;

// Check if the product is already in the cart
foreach ( $cart as $cart_item ) {
    if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id ) {
        $is_in_cart = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Output the "Ajouter au Panier" button
$add_to_cart_button = sprintf(
    '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button-primary xsmall rounded wide %s add-to-cart-button" data-product_id="%d" %s>%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
    esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
    esc_attr( $product_id ),
    isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
);

// Show the "Ajouter au Panier" button
echo $add_to_cart_button;

// Show "Voir le Panier" button if the product is in the cart
if ( $is_in_cart ) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" class="button voir_panier_button" style="display:block;">%s</a>',
        esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ),
        esc_html__( 'Voir le Panier', 'woocommerce' )
    );
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        let viewCartButtonShown = false;

        $('.add-to-cart-button').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var button = $(this);
            var productId = button.data('product_id');
            var viewCartButton = $('.voir_panier_button');

            // Check if the product is already in the cart
            if (viewCartButton.length === 0) {
                // If the "Voir le Panier" button is not already shown
                button.parent().append(viewCartButton);
                viewCartButton.show();
                viewCartButtonShown = true; // Mark the button as shown
            } else {
                // If the product is already in the cart, hide the "Voir le Panier" button
                viewCartButton.hide();
            }

            // Optional: Hide the "added_to_cart wc-forward" button
            $('.added_to_cart.wc-forward').hide();
        });
    });
</script>


To ensure that the Voir le Panier button remains visible for products that are already in the cart even after a page refresh in WooCommerce, you'll need to ensure that your PHP and Javascript logic are correctly handling the state persistence. From what you've provided the PHP part of your logic seems mostly set up to check if the product is in the cart and then show the button. However, there might be some tweaks necessary to ensure everything works seamlessly across page reloads.
First, the following refined code is for PHP part to check the cart status.
// remaining part of code 
echo sprintf(
    '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button add-to-cart-button %s" data-product_id="%d" %s>%s</a>',
    esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()),
    esc_attr(isset($args['quantity']) ? $args['quantity'] : 1),
    esc_attr(isset($args['class']) ? $args['class'] : 'button'),
    esc_attr($product_id),
    isset($args['attributes']) ? wc_implode_html_attributes($args['attributes']) : '',
    esc_html($product->add_to_cart_text())
);
// remaining part of code. 

For Javascript refinement you can do something like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // This could be simplified or even unnecessary if PHP is doing its job correctly
    var productId = '<?php echo $product_id; ?>';  // Make sure product ID is echoed correctly in JS
    var isInCart = <?php echo $is_in_cart ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;

    if (isInCart) {
        $('.voir_panier_button').show();  // Make sure this class matches the button you want to show
    } else {
        $('.voir_panier_button').hide();
    }
});
</script>


thanks brother for the help iv try it before and still same problem but i did and alternative solution based on java that it change the text and the color of the button but the only thing im have issue with now is when i remove somthiing from the cart the button dosent back to intial state

They are multiple mistakes in your approach, and you are makings things much more complicated than they should be.
You don't need to make changes in the template, and either add any JavaScript code. Before overriding any template file, always try to use available hooks, made for customizations.
So first, remove the template override and any other related code.
Then simply use the following (defining the "View cart" text in French):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 3 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $html, $product, $args  ) {
    $view_cart_text = esc_html__('View cart', 'woocommerce'); // Define view cart text

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->get_id() == $item['product_id'] ) {
            $class = esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' );
            // Add "added" to the html class attribute
            $html  = str_replace($class, $class . ' added', $html); 

            // Append View cart button html
            $html .= sprintf( 
                '<a href="%s" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="%s">%s</a>', 
                wc_get_cart_url(), $view_cart_text, $view_cart_text 
            );
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Changing background colors:
To change buttons background colors, don't use JavaScript, instead, use CSS…
You can add the following CSS rules to your child theme style.css file:
a.ajax_add_to_cart, a.added_to_cart{background-color: green !important;}
a.ajax_add_to_cart.added{background-color: grey !important;}

or add the following to your child theme functions.php file:
add_action('wp_head', 'wp_head_custom_inline_css', 99999);
function wp_head_custom_inline_css() {
    ?>
    <style>
    a.ajax_add_to_cart, a.added_to_cart{background-color: green !important;}
    a.ajax_add_to_cart.added{background-color: grey !important;}
    </style>
    <?php
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Don't we do: $args['class'] ?? 'button'?

@mickmackusa First, I just picked WooCommerce existing code from loop/add-to-cart.php template file… I suppose that the reason to use isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' is that we need to check that 'class' array key exist in $args array, avoiding an error if it doesn't.

Right.  And the two statements are synonymous.

So, to resume:$args['class'] ?? 'button' is similar to $args['class'] ? $args['class'] : 'button', but not a good replacement for isset($args['class']) ? $args['class'] : 'button'… :)

Ah, good, a learning moment.  It is an identical replacement.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#:~:text=This%20is%20equivalent%20to%3A  What you were describing is the Elvis operator, not my recommended null coalescing operator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571460/2943403

thank you so much it works well but when you refresh the page it goes back to the initial state I want it to keep showing the buttons for the products in the cart even if he refreshes and when he remove the product from card and refresh the buttons back to initial state

@MO3 I don't have the issue you describe. For me, it works perfectly, even when refreshing the page…  It seems that there is something else that is making trouble, in your case.

alright thanks brother for the help
